# Shrinkwrap div to wrapped content

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to size a container div according to its children, which can wrap onto multiple lines.  If the children (blue boxes) do wrap, the container's width is 100% (black border, below). I'd like to avoid this, and set the container to the maximum width of any of its children.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
}
.child {
  width: 500px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help? I'm aware this can be done with javascript, but I'd prefer a css-only solution as it *seems* so simple. Thanks!

**Update:**
This is a snippet showing how it should look, but it in this case it prevents the `.child` divs from appearing inline (which I want to allow when there's room):

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: min-content;
}
.child {
  width: 500px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: .child remove inline-block and use float: left;

Comment: You can use JavaScript fir this.

Comment: Thanks, but using `float: left` I still get the parent div to be wider than the children. In the OP I've said I'd prefer not to have to use javascript, but I guess I have to.

Answer (score 4):

you can try using on the container element

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: min-content;
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue well, but just remember that it requires vendor prefixes for different browsers. So it will need 

     `width: -moz-min-content;
     width: -webkit-min-content; 
     width: min-content;`

Comment: meh, to be honest, I don't think it solves the problem because it's a bit vague in his description. You are correct about vendor prefix.

Comment: Thanks - this is how I'd like it to look when the `.child` divs are wrapped, but `width: min-content` seems to prevent them from appearing inline.

Comment: Vendor prefixes for min-content may no longer be needed in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: min-content;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The 'nowrap' is needed so this also works with text and other inline items.

(Note: I could not edit the answer above due to too many pending edits.)

Comment: That completely disables wrapping, though.